# Force Google Maps to display my location with correct zoom

Tags: google-maps

Whenever I open Google Maps (by typing `maps.google.com` URL) in Opera, I always see map of Central Europe, not my location. How can I force GM to display my location?

The "[Give Maps permission to use your location](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/152197?hl=en)" article does not have specific instructions for Opera browser. When I tried to apply instructions for Chrome, it turned out, that I have option `Ask me when a site tries to track my physical location (recommended)` selected. Even so, Opera never asked me, if I want to allow Google Maps to know my location. I also don't have GM among exceptions for location tracking.

When I click `Show My Location` button in Google Maps, the location is correctly determined (even though I still see no question from Opera and even though `maps.google.com` are not added to exception list -- strange), but **zoom remains o 6x, so I still see map of entire Central Europe**.

<sub>In the past Opera has asked me for this for few other sites (like wizzair.com in my case) and thus I'm pretty sure, tha this issue is with Google Maps not with Opera (and thus asking here, not in Super User).</sub>